# What is the maximum record count for a DataGrid in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

What is the maximum record count for a DataGrid in VB.NET? Is there any limit?

Answer (score 3):

There is no explicit limitation in a DataGrid.

However it is constrained by both it's internal data structures which tend to count rows in terms of Integer.  This means the hard limit is Integer.MaxValue

On a 32 bit system though, you will hit problems long before you hit Integer.MaxValue rows.  Every item added to the DataGrid has a certain amount of overhead.  If each item only has 4 bytes of overhead, you will max out at Integer.MaxValue / 4.  This is really a simplistic view of the problem though because it doesn't take into account other controls, internal WinForms resources, etc ...

How many records are you thinking of adding?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any hard limit outside the physical limitations of available memory or perhaps Integer.MaxValue.  I wouldn't be too surprised if there is, though.

What's more important is that a datagrid is a *visual* construct shown to *real users*.  Users won't much appreciate a grid with 1000 items it, let alone 100,000+ (which I have seen before).

The point is that rather than worrying about the maximum records you can stuff in there, you're better off implementing paging or a better search mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The `Count` property of the DataGridView.Rows collection is an `Integer`, so the normal range for 4-byte signed integers should apply as an effective limit:  0 to 2,147,483,647

As to what the Rows collection can actually hold, I'm not sure... it would depend on what your application is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Integer.MaxValue, I guess it depends on the memory available to the application & already used.

Why are you thinking of filling the grid with all rows at once?
It doesn't make sense showing users all the records.